# MongoDB Count number of articles with author

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a MongoDB set up as follows:

```
 {_id: id,
  'article_information': ...
  'AU':[list of authors]
   ..other fields...
 }
```

I am trying to use aggregate to count the number of documents (articles) per each author. Duplicate are OK at this point. Combining authors is another layer of processing, owing to changing names, different spellings of names with accents an so on.

I want output similar to the following:

```
 'Author 1': Count of documents mentioning author 1, 
            ...
 'Author N': Count of documents mentioning author n,
```

The below attempt yields an empty list:

```
 collection.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":'AU',"count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

I thought that the error might be because `$AU` is a list of strings, but `db.collection.distinct('AU')` returns a list of strings, not a list of lists.

In SQL style syntax I view the query as the following put in a for-loop that iterates over a list of authors. I'm not sure how to write that in Mongo.

```
 SELECT * from collection WHERE author IN AUTHOR_LIST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `$unwind` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)) the collection first by author and then `$group` it as you are doing right now:

```
pipeline = [{"$unwind": "$AU"}, 
            {"$group": {"_id": "$AU", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

You have an example in the [pymongo aggregation framework docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html).